# How to remove prev and next style from owl carousel

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

How can I remove prev and next style from navigation buttons in owl carousel.

Here's image to show what I'm talking about:

http://lookpic.com/O/t2/1725/N7d763L6.png

http://oi58.tinypic.com/2vnncl0.jpg

Here's my styles for the buttons

```
.owl-next{    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 51px;
    background: url('../images/sp.png');
    background-position: -47px -19px;}
.owl-prev {
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 51px;
    background: url('../images/sp.png');
    background-position: 1px -19px;
}
```

Comment: image does not shown

Comment: here's another link
http://oi58.tinypic.com/2vnncl0.jpg

Comment: The CSS that comes with the plugin handles those styles - just remove what you don't need from there.

Comment: You can change display:block; to display:none;

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
   navigation : false 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Now in the new version, you have to use in your js code

```
navText: [" ", " "]
```

if you wanna hide next and previous button.